# PHPMyAdmin does not show the size of a view

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have database which has a view called **categories_view** for some purpose i need to tell the size of a view (KB).

i have access of phpmyadmin of database but it does not show the size of view is there another way to see it?

see image for reference.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: A view is just a SELECT statement which does not hold any data.

Comment: but i have a view which is not cascaded, that means any update in table would not affect the data of view. that means at any point in time view will contain all data, dont it suppose to give me size in that case.